# How to handle clicks on multiple tags inside a "div" tag-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im trying to handle a click event on a `div`.There are 2 separate click events that I need to handle on `div`, one is on element `<a>` and another on element `<span>` I have a psedo code for the if-else conditions depending on what element I have clicked.
below is my function after rendering the page:

```
afterrender: function() {
                Ext.fly('div').createChild({
                      tag: 'div',
                      html: "<label class='highlight'> Try the new <a href='#'>Beta version</a><span class='icon-clear'></span></label>"
                  }).on("click", function(e) {
                    if (e.target is <a>) {
                      //do some fun
                    }else if (e.target is <span>) {
                        //do some func
                   }
                }, this, { delegate: 'label' });  
        }
```

I'm not sure how to check which element was clicked to execute fun depending on that element..Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getTarget` method on the event, which will climb check if the event target (or any parent) matches the selector.

```
if (e.getTarget('a')) {
} else if (e.getTarget('span') {
} else if (e.getTarget('.someClassName') {
}
// etc
```